# Isn't it time to stop using the term "god" or "goddess" for our ideals?

Tags: gods, karma, dharma, bhakti

Dharmic traditions are not encoded "belief systems", so why borrow terms from Christianity or Islam? Some may argue that we can use such terms "generically", but why?  Does Deva, Ishvara, and Bhagwan translate to "God"? Of course not! Deva/Asura are the base qualities, Ishvara are higher ideals, and Bhagwan is anyone who displays such qualities in their behaviour.
There is no such thing as "pictures and idols".
Hindu traditions are not "idol worship". Vigraha and Pratima merely represent "crystallized knowledge" of a perspective (darsana).
A darsana is a perspective on the truth.
A deity therefore merely represents a darsana in a material form, a visual encyclopedia, one that is rich in symbology.
A darshan gives you the objective, the key concepts, the techniques, and the path to realizing that objective or ideal.
Let's at least start by rejecting Abrahamic beliefs such as "God". Every Indian tradition is a perspective on your own true nature.
It is why we don't have the concept of conversion between dharmic darsana or sampradaya.
You are what you are!
Tatvamasi.
You're it.

Comment: Please read forum rules